# How can get String that I need to paste to file from log or result of command by using bash in ubuntu

Tags: linux, string, bash, ubuntu

I would like to log temperature of cpu, for that I make a shell script which 
run 'sensors' command then put it in text file. However I don't need all of result. I just want paste line that has temperature info.

It is result of 'sensors' command below:

```
hotsname$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +102.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +51.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)
```

I would like to copy and past a line that show temperature.
(ex: `temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +102.0°C)` <- this part)

What can I try for this?
please tell me how or what keyword I should look into.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use grep:

```
sensors | grep -E 'crit = ?[[:digit:]]*.*'
```

To strictly check with 'degree Celsius' in the grep:

```
sensors | grep -E "crit = ?[[:digit:]]*.*$(echo $'\xc2\xb0'C)"
```